# Auto execute custom scripts after generating database from model in EF

Tags: database, entity-framework, sql-scripts

I'm using EF 4.0 and I'm constantly performing **Generate database from model** in my edmx. After each time, I have to execute a bunch of different scripts other than the auto generated edmx.sql script.

I'm wondering if there is a way to add something like post-processing to the project to do this automatically.